# Perl6: How could I make all warnings fatal?

Tags: perl, error-handling, warnings, raku

How could I make all warnings in Perl6 fatal, so that the script dies as soon as a warning appears on the screen.

---

`CONTROL { when CX::Warn { note $_; exit 1 } }` dies more often.

This script dies with `CONTROL { when CX::Warn { note $_; exit 1 } }` but not with `use fatal`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
use v6;

my @a = 1 .. 4;
@a[5] = 6;
my @b;

for @a -> $i {
    @b.push( ~$i );
}

say "=====\n" x 3;
```

Comment: perhaps something like `CONTROL { when CX::Warn { note $_; exit 1 } }` in the script's mianline?

Comment: @Christoph: Could you turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warnings are control exceptions of type `CX::Warn` that are resumed by default. If you want to change that behaviour, you need to add a `CONTROL` block, in your case something like this:

```
CONTROL {
    when CX::Warn {
        note $_;
        exit 1;
    }
}
```

Ignoring all warning instead of making them fatal would look like this:

```
CONTROL {
    when CX::Warn { .resume }
}
```

Comment: The downside of this is that this does not produce fatal warnings when uninitialized values are given to `say`.  I don't know how to fix this yet

Answer (score 3):

You can make all exceptions immediately fatal with 'use fatal'.  For instance, this code will not throw an error until you attempt to read from $file, so it will reach the 'say' line.  If you uncomment 'use fatal', it will die immediately at the 'open' statement, and not reach the 'say' line.

For more fine-grained control, see the try/CATCH system for exceptions.

```
# use fatal;
my $file = open 'nonexistent', :r;
say 'Reached here';
my @lines = $file.IO.lines;
```

Comment: I prefer `CONTROL { when CX::Warn { note $_; exit 1 } }` from Christoph's comment, because it dies more often.

Comment: As I understand it, using "ucfirst($someString) will generate a warning about using deprecated code, but use fatal will not turn this into a fatal exception.

Comment: Good catch.  I wonder if that's because 'use fatal' applies to Exceptions, and maybe deprecated code doesn't produce an Exception, but a warning at an earlier level.

Comment: @AaronBaugher: `use fatal` makes failures throw immediately; however, warnings do already throw - they are just resumed by default