# How to die on undefined values?

Tags: raku

I am attempting to work with a hash in Raku, but when I put some fake values into it (intentionally) like

```
say %key<fake_key>;
```

I get

`(Any)`

but I want the program to die in such occurrences, as Perl does, because this implies that important data is missing.

For example,

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings 'FATAL' => 'all';
use autodie ':all';

my %hash;
print "$hash{y}\n";
```

as of 5.26.1 produces

```
Use of uninitialized value $hash{"y"} in concatenation (.) or string at undefined.pl line 8.
Command exited with non-zero status 255
```

How can I get the equivalent of `use warnings 'FATAL' => 'all'` and `use autodie qw(:all)` in Raku?

Comment: Perl5 doesn't die if you reference a hash key that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Scimon it will with `use warnings` which is what I want

Comment: `use warnings` won't make it die just throw a warning.

Comment: What you probably want is a Role for your Hash that dies if a non existent key is created. Right now https://modules.perl6.org/dist/Hash::Restricted:cpan:ELIZABETH Hash::Restricted would work if you aren't planning on modifying the Hash.

Comment: @Scimon please see the clarification, I've shown the perl5 that I want to emulate in Perl6

Comment: That's not dying though. It's giving a warning. 
And the warning isn't about the fact the key doesn't exist it's about using the returned undefined value in the string interpolation.

Comment: Note if in perl6 you call say "%key<fake_key>"; you get basically the same error. Anyway if you really want it to die feel free to use the KeyRequired role :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Aiui your question is:

> I'm looking for `use autodie qw(:all)` & `use warnings 'FATAL' => 'all'` in Raku

## The equivalent of Perl's `autodie` in Raku

Aiui the equivalent of `use autodie qw(:all)` in Perl is `use fatal;` in Raku. This is a lexically scoped effect (at least it is in Raku).

[The `autodie` section in the Perl-to-Raku nutshell guide](https://docs.raku.org/language/5to6-nutshell#autodie) explains that routines now return [`Failure`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Failure)s to indicate errors.

[The `fatal` pragma](https://docs.raku.org/language/pragmas#fatal)  makes returning a `Failure` from a routine automatically throw an exception that contains the `Failure`. Unless you provide code that catches them, these exceptions that wrap `Failure`s automatically die.

## The equivalent of Perl's `use warnings 'FATAL'` in Raku

Aiui the equivalent of `use warnings 'FATAL' => 'all'` in Perl is `CONTROL { when CX::Warn { note $_; exit 1 } }` in Raku. This is a lexically scoped effect (at least it is in Raku).

[`CONTROL` exceptions](https://docs.raku.org/language/phasers#index-entry-Phasers__CONTROL-CONTROL) explains how these work.

`CONTROL` exceptions are a subset of all exceptions that are `.resume`'d by default -- the program stays alive by default when they're thrown.

The Raku code I've provided (which is lifted from [How could I make all warnings fatal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34747960/perl6-how-could-i-make-all-warnings-fatal) which you linked to) instead makes `CONTROL` exceptions die (due to the [`exit`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/exit) routine).

Returning to your current question text:

```
say %key<fake_key>; # (Any)
```

> I want the program to die in such occurrences ...

Use either Jonathan++'s answer (use `put`, which, unlike `say`, isn't trying to keep your program alive) or Scimon++'s `KeyRequired` answer which will make accessing of a non-existent key fatal.

> ... as Perl does ...

Only if you use `use warnings 'FATAL' ...`, just as Raku does if you use the equivalent.

> ... because this implies that important data is missing.

Often it implies unimportant data is missing, or even important data that you don't want defined some of the time you attempt to access it, so both Perls and Raku default to keeping your program alive and require that you tell it what you want if you want something different.

You can use the above constructs to get the precise result you want and they'll be limited to a given variable (if you use the `KeyRequired` role) or statement (using `put` instead of `say`) or lexical scope (using a pragma or the `CONTROL` block).

Answer (score 11):

You can create a role to do this. A simple version would be :

```
role KeyRequired { 
    method AT-KEY( \key ) { 
        die "Key {key} not found" unless self.EXISTS-KEY(key); 
        nextsame; 
    } 
};
```

Then you create your hash with : `my %key does KeyRequired;` and it will die if you request a non existent key.

Comment: `key.Str (elem) self.keys` is O(N), you should really use `unless self.EXISTS-KEY(key)`

Comment: I'm looking for `use autodie qw(:all)` & `use warnings 'FATAL' => 'all'` in Perl6

Comment: I just used hash keys as an example, I was hoping for something more general :/

Answer (score 10):

The simple answer is to not use `say`.

```perl6
say %key<fake_key>;
# (Any)

put %key<fake_key>;
# Use of uninitialized value of type Any in string context.
# Methods .^name, .perl, .gist, or .say can be used to stringify it to something
# meaningful.
#   in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

`say` calls `.gist` which prints enough information for a human to understand what was printed.
`put` just tries to turn it into a `Str` and print that, but in this case it produces an error.

Answer (score 9):

Perl 5 warns, not dies, in this case. Perl 6 will do the same if equivalent code is used:

```
my %key;
print "%key<fake_key>\n"; # Gives a warning
```

Or, more neatly, use `put`:

```
my %key;
put %key<fake_key>;
```

The `put` routine ("print using terminator") will stringify the value, which is what triggers the warning about use of an undefined value in string context.

By contrast, `say` does not stringify, but instead calls `.gist` on the object, and prints whatever it returns. In the case of an undefined value, the gist of it is the name of its type, wrapped in parentheses. In general, `say` - which uses `.gist` underneath - gives more information. For example, consider an array:

```
my @a = 1..5;
put @a;          # 1 2 3 4 5
say @a;          # [1 2 3 4 5]
```

Where `put` just joins the elements with spaces, but `say` represents the structure and that it's an array.

Comment: thanks, `put` is definitely useful, I'm surprised that I don't see it more often in the documentation.  I'm looking for the perl6 equivalent of `use warnings 'FATAL' => 'all'; use autodie qw(:all);` this is close https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34747960/perl6-how-could-i-make-all-warnings-fatal but it will still miss errors